# Postgres - Querying table with many to many relationship

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My schema is composed like this:

`channel` -> `channels_categories` -> `category`

A channel can have many categories, and categories can belong to many channels.

When i query for channels, i would like to get the channels categories with them.

Anyway if i use `JOIN` i will simply get the channel duplicated for each category.

```
[
  {
    "channel_name": "Channel1",
    "category_name": "Category1",
    "category_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "channel_name": "Channel1",
    "category_name": "Category2"
    "category_id": "2"
  }
]
```

The ideal result format (JSON) would be something like:

```
{
  channel_name: 'Channel1',
  categories: [{/**category**/}, ....]
}
```

Is there a way i can achieve this result format just with SQL?

Comment: Just use [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) as aggregation function on the categories and [concat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) to add the square brackets.

Comment: Let me understand, this would work in the case that category is just a string? What if i also have categories id in the results?

Comment: If you also want to join them to a string you should be able to do the same. Like `select channel_name, string_agg(category_name, ','), sting_agg(category_id, ',') ...` I don't have a postgresDB at hand right now to try it out

Comment: Seems like you didn't use `group by channel_name`, I'll write an complete answer when I have a postgresDB at hand.

Comment: @RonaldFindling yes, i learned that and solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely untested but I've looked at the manual for JSON functions and it looks like the following might work:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
    'channel_name', channel.name,
    'categories',   jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
            'category_id',   category.id,
            'category_name', category.name
        )
    )
)
from channel
join channels_categories on channel.id = channel_id
join category on category.id = category_id
group by channel.id
```

This assumes that `channel` has a primary key called `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you really want the result in the JSON format, this answer is about combining and merging attributes into JSON lists.

You can use [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) and [concat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) to combine the category_name and category_id to lists like this:

```
select channel_name, 
  concat('[', string_agg(category_name, ','), ']') as category_names, 
  concat('[', string_agg(cast(category.id as text), ','), ']') as category_ids 
from 
  channel inner join channel_category on channel.id = channel_category.channel_id 
  inner join category on channel_category.category_id = category.id
group by channel_name;
```

Which produces results like that:

```
| channel_name |    category_names    | category_ids |
| channel1     | [category1,category2]| [1,2]        |
```

For a complete JSON result [melpomene's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) answer seems to fit your needs way better than this.